# How to add field new in account bacs in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters, hooks

i was looking for a way to add a new field to woocommerce bank account info, my theme has no child theme and i put my code in functions.php

I found the solution but it doesn't work.

```php
function newfield_bacs_account_field( $account_fields, $order_id ) {
    $account_fields['test_added' ] = array(
        'label' => __( 'labelfield', 'woocommerce' ),
         'value' => __( 'valuefield', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
    return $account_fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_bacs_account_fields', 'newfield_bacs_account_field', 10, 2);
```

i have tried thousands of times but still not working

Comment: Which functions.php?

Comment: I'd make sure this code is being loaded and run, e.g. deliberately put a syntax error in the file and see what happens, or error_log() from inside your function and next to the line that adds the filter, or `throw new Error("new BACS fields");` in the same places.

Comment: You don't need the __() function since that's trying to load translated text from the WooCommerce language pot which won't be there. Instead you can either load the translations from your own namespace (not woocommerce) or just hard-code strings for now.

Comment: Also I'm slightly surprised the filter doesn't pass in $bacs_account from [the calling code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/7.7.2/plugins/woocommerce/includes/gateways/bacs/class-wc-gateway-bacs.php#L315), since all of the default values are read from that, and I guess any new data you've got would be read from or computed from those values as well. Out of interest, what's the new field that you're adding for?